# How do I insert a full width element into a three column CSS grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a parent:

```
    .images{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 40px;
    }
```

Which organises its children into a grid of three columns.

When I click an image I am using JS to insert a container at the end of that row. I want that container (".info-row") to span all three columns and be full width.

I know how to do this with floats, but I'm trying to get to grips with CSS Grid.

Comment: see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row-start-end take a look at the short hand `grid-column:1 / span 3;` see also https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as other mentioned you can use:

`grid-column: 1 / 4;` or `grid-column: span 3;`

on element, and you'll also probably need:
 `grid-auto-flow: row dense;`

on container  to fill the gaps in grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the starting and end line of a cell in the grid.

```
.info-row {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer pretty quickly. On the child element you need to add the "grid-column" property. This allows it to span over a set number of columns. The way it works is a bit counter-intuitive, the values correspond to the beginning or end of each column. So for a three column span the property needs to be "grid-column: 1 / 4;" where the first number is the starting point of the span and the second number is the end point.

Comment: It's not really counter-intuitive. The values represent grid lines. So you're starting at the first grid column line (left side of first column) and ending on the last grid column line (right side of third column). It's called "line-based placement" in the spec.